# asp.net handling Back button event after Logout

Tags: asp.net

In the logout link button click event I have cleared the session variables. I am checking these session variables for null values at each page's load event. If it has the null value redirecting them to the login page.
But the problem is whenever I click the browser back button, the page_load event won't get called. For that I have cleared the the browser cache history.
Please help me someone where I am missing...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best method for forcing cache expiration in ASP.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/533867/whats-the-best-method-for-forcing-cache-expiration-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to make sure the pages behind the login (those that can only be accessed after login) are not cached in the browser:

```
Page.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
```

If using forms authentication, you will also need to abandon the session and logout:

```
Session.Abandon();
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433485/asp-net-handling-back-button-event-after-logout), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589285/how-to-disable-back-button-in-browser-when-user-logout-in-asp-net-c) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686946/asp-net-authentication-login-and-logout-with-browser-back-button).

Comment: -1 "those that can only be accessed after login" that's every webpage on the website.  So you are basically saying disable caching for every page on the website.  +1 if you can explain.

Comment: @sub13 - If he wants that clicking the back page will not show the last page (assuming one has to be logged in to see that page), he can't have the page cached by the browser. Please explain what other mechanism you would use to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, hope it works

> Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
>
> Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1));
>
> Response.Cache.SetNoStore();