# how to implement logout functionality in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, logout

hii

how can i implement logout feature on my page so that user is redirected to a new page and is not allowed to view previous page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to disable back button in browser when user logout in asp.net c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589285/how-to-disable-back-button-in-browser-when-user-logout-in-asp-net-c)

Comment: This is typically done via the user session. There are numerous solutions for this in .Net - google is your friend.

Answer (score 3):

```
  if (SessionConfig.Current.UserType != null)
        Response.Redirect("~/Logout.aspx?UserType=" + SessionConfig.Current.UserType,false);
    else
        Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx",false);
```

where sessionconfig is a session variable already declared.

```
 public static SessionConfig Current
        {
            get
            {
                SessionConfig session =
                  (SessionConfig)HttpContext.Current.Session["__SessionConfig__"];
                if (session == null)
                {
                    session = new SessionConfig();
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["__SessionConfig__"] = session;
                }
                return session;
            }
        }
```

Just put this in button click event and change to your home page in homepage.aspx . It will redirect the page and you cannot see the old page

Comment: where do I declare the SessionConfig variable

Answer (score 1):

Just add  `LogoutAction="RedirectToLoginPage"` to the login control and it will solve your problem.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [ASP.net Login Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d51ttbhx%28VS.85%29.aspx) 
if you want the user to not be allowed to back to the previous page see [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533867/whats-the-best-method-for-forcing-cache-expiration-in-asp-net/534296#534296)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, enable asp.net security permissions and set anonymous users access as Denied.
then, use asp.net log-in control and set it up as you wish...