# disable browser back button using C#.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disabling Back button on the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87422/disabling-back-button-on-the-browser)

i want to disable browser back button without using javascript function forward().
because it remain on this page.

I want to totally disable browser back button like banking sites

Please send me code for that i need it

thank to all of you in advance

Comment: i don't know completly , but i think we cannot do this from the server side

Comment: check this. works fine
http://geekswithblogs.net/Frez/archive/2010/05/18/back-button-issue-after-logout-in-asp.net.aspx

Comment: also refer  http://stackoverflow.com/a/28458499/2089963

Answer (score 0):

Do not disable expected browser behaviour. Make your pages handle the possibility of users going back a page or two;Take idea from followings:
[Disable browser's back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961188/disable-browsers-back-button)
[Disabling Back button on the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87422/disabling-back-button-on-the-browser)
[How to disable the back button in browser when user logout in asp.net c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589285/how-to-disable-back-button-in-browser-when-user-logout-in-asp-net-c)