# After logging out from Asp.Net application, history.forward() not working in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, session

My application is in developed in **Asp.Net** with the coding language as **VB.Net**, the issues is after the user logouts if the back button of the browser is used then the application redirects to Login page.

**What i tried:**

I used **history.forward()** in my script under head, but its not working if i use **Mozila Firefox** browser.

**Solution is welcomed.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to make sure the pages behind the login (those that can only be accessed after login) are not cached in the browser:

```
Page.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
```

If using forms authentication, you will also need to abandon the session and logout:

```
Session.Abandon();
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
```

source

[reference-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686946/asp-net-authentication-login-and-logout-with-browser-back-button) [reference-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589285/how-to-disable-back-button-in-browser-when-user-logout-in-asp-net-c)

Comment: @peter thanks but i have same problem after using your solution please give proper solution

Comment: Vishwanathan Iyer, i clear browser history but it again not working