# How to stop form resubmission on browser back button being pressed by the client

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

How can I stop my form from being resubmitted in asp.net when the client clicks on the browser back button.

Comment: yes.. like clearing cookies or chache.. but still not working

Comment: can you show me the code you have tried ?

Comment: Session.Clear();
            Session.Abandon();
            Session.RemoveAll();
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1));
            Response.Cache.SetNoStore();

Comment: The OP has posted a somewhat misleading question. They actually mean 'How do I stop form resubmission on browser back button being pressed'. Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463843/asp-net-expiring-a-page-when-navigating-back

Comment: possible duplicate of [Post Redirect Get in asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153018/post-redirect-get-in-asp-net)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17905785/how-to-prevent-user-from-going-back-to-the-login-page-after-successful-login-usi here is another one of what you are seeking of

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the resubmission of a page redirecting the POST action to a GET one.

Keep a look in [PRG Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) and [how implement](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/implement-prg-pattern-in-mvc-architecture/) it in C# if using MVC or try try [this approach](http://aspalliance.com/687_Preventing_Duplicate_Record_Insertion_on_Page_Refresh.all#top)