# Warning, page expired page in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net

I want to protect the users by not going back to the previous pages, consider the ex in banking sites where if we click "back" button, it shows "warning page expired" page.

In Asp.Net, how to do that.

I tried with the following options, but it doesnt work.

Option 1:-

```
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
```

Option 2 :-

```
<meta http-equiv="PRAGMA" content="NO-CACHE" />
```

Option 3:- on Page_Load()

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache); 
        Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
        Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-1));
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also I've this issue. Waiting for response.

Comment: Bottom line: your application must do this server-side. See this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/961188/304683). Note **all** the answers and comments, not just the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Edit following line in your solution:

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.ServerAndNoCache)
```

Comment: Similar post > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64059/is-there-a-way-to-keep-a-page-from-rendering-once-a-person-has-logged-out-but-hi