# I tried to get session for my login page to content page, when I logout and press back button it redirects to my content page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

My login page code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    if (!Session["userid"].Equals(String.Empty))
    {
        Response.Redirect("Welcome.aspx");
    }
}
protected void CheckBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("userreg.aspx");
}
```

Content page code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["userid"].Equals(String.Empty))
    {
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
              }
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session.Abandon();
    Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
}
```

Comment: could you explain your problem in more detail?

Comment: after logout. im able to go back using back browse button. even though having session

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to keep a page from rendering once a person has logged out but hit the "back" button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64059/is-there-a-way-to-keep-a-page-from-rendering-once-a-person-has-logged-out-but-hi)